# how to use the ** operator

Tags: python, operators

Hi I'm trying to use the power operator in Python and I do not know how to combined from the user input.
Any one can help me how to use it.

```
import math
input_1 = raw_input('Please enter an integer:  ')
input_2 = raw_input('Please enter another integer:  ')
var_result = input_1.int() ** input_2.int()
print var_result
```

I get this when I run it:

```
~ mgregory$ python foo.py
Please enter an integer:  12
Please enter another integer:  12
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 4, in <module>
    var_result = input_1.int() ** input_2.int()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'int
```

Comment: What are you trying to do and what are you experiencing?

Comment: I think you'll save yourself a lot of trouble, in the long run, if you complete the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/).

Comment: Thank you, for you advise I'm learning Python and I will try to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `int` type to create `int` objects

```
var_result = int(input_1) ** int(input_2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
input_1 = int(raw_input('Please enter an integer:  '))
input_2 = int(raw_input('Please enter another integer:  '))
var_result = input_1 ** input_2
print var_result
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you want this

```
import math
input_1 = raw_input('Please enter an integer:  ')
input_2 = raw_input('Please enter another integer:  ')
var_result = int(input_1) ** int(input_2)
print var_result
```

you need to convert strings input_1 and input_" to int

Answer (score 1):

Two notes:

1. `int()` is used incorrectly. It should be called as `int(input_1)`. You are also typecasting to type `int` when you may want `float` (see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex)
2. If you use `math.pow(input_1, input_2)` the arguments will automatically be typecast to `float` which may be more convenient (details: https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.pow).

So you could do something like so:

```
import math
input_1 = raw_input('Please enter an integer:  ')
input_2 = raw_input('Please enter another integer:  ')
var_result = math.pow(input_1, input_2)
print var_result
```